# What's the best way to DllImport or otherwise P/Invoke WaitOnAddress, and other functions in the api-ms-* DLLs?

Tags: .net, winapi, pinvoke

I want to `WaitOnAddress` from managed code. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706898(v=vs.85).aspx) states that the DLL is `kernel32.dll`. But `dumpbin /exports c:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll` does not list it, and sure enough, using `[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]` does not work. It is exported from `api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll` (a forwarding export, forwarding it to `kernel32.dll`), which is in the `c:\windows\system32\downlevel` directory on my Windows 10 system, and `[DllImport("api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll")]` appears work on my system, but is it the way to go? I don't see it documented anywhere.

Comment: In C++ if you build a project that references it, you will be linked directly to api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll (because Synchronization.lib points to it) so I guess it's the way to go... doesn't smells super future proof...

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks, I thought about it, but having a companion native DLL would be a massive PITA (need to watch out for bitness, have to deploy it etc.), hence my question.

Comment: The MSDN article is not correct, notable is that they just don't have a good way to document this.  A newish Win8 api like this can be forwarded to any DLL at runtime.  So yes, you really do have to use the api-ms-etcetera DLL.  Beware of Win7.